# How to catch or send ctr + p in c to a process, sending ctr + p to qemu with kill

Tags: c, signals, qemu, xv6

I am writing an test program to test my Xv6 on Qemu, and i want to send to Qemu the ctr + p shortcut key bind that executed a function in Xv6.

I don't know what is actually ctr + p, i assume its a signal since the shell also support this shortcut,however maybe its not becuase i don't think every shell shortcut is a signal, but i'm not actually sure how can i send the ctr + p from my test program to Qemu.

I have Qemu process group id and i can send a stream of text to it too.